# How to show field of a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

`show fields from table_name`
and
 `show columns from table_name`

shows `Fields`, `Type`,`Null`,`Key`,`Default`,`Extra`

[image]

But, I want to show only `Fields` so that I can copy field's name to use another(e.g. inserting data or making csv file because csv file need to have column name in 1st row).

What is the command to view this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 'your_table'
AND table_schema = 'database_name'
```

Comment: Please don't answer duplicates if possible.